# Accessing Item Class Properties from the line on Sales Order

Tags: line, netsuite

I have a custom property on the Class (custcol_classorder) that i want to populate to the sales order lines based on the class selected, i have this working when items are manually added to sales order but not when added via the Add Multiple button.

there is another mandatory field that the user must fill in so i have a workflow to trigger off that to update my classorder field.  If I user {line.class} i can get the internal id off the class but how do i get to the custom property on the class?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this sort of thing can be done by setting up custom transaction column fields and 'sourcing' them from the item's class's custom fields.

As you have discovered 'Add Multiple' skips client and workflow scripts.

If you really need those values scripted you could do it in a before submit user event.